# Search Engine Optimization for Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment, seo

I have created an Angular app and successfully deployed it in google firebase with the free tire.

I am able to access my website with the firebase provided link but I am unable to search and get that on google.

[Here is my link](https://bhanuprakashpalagati.web.app/)

Can I active SEO for this I mean if I search bhanu Prakash can I get my website listed on the browser with the free tire.

Or do I need to upgrade my plan then it will work?

Please provide any links for reference when you answer so that we are on the same page.

Thank You

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281367/where-to-find-answers-to-seo-questions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is SEO, not programming